# авторизация в ВК (Java)

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, httpclient

Я понимаю: вопрос не новый, нашел несколько очень подобных реализаций, но не одна у меня не работает((.. Первая проблема возникает вот где:

```
HttpClient client=HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
StringBuilder request =new StringBuilder();
request.append("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=").append(APP_ID).
        append("&display=page&redirect_uri=").append(REDIR_URI).append("&scope=").
        append(SCOPE).append("&response_type=token&v=5.45");
HttpGet get=new HttpGet(request.toString());
HttpResponse resp=client.execute(get);
System.out.println(resp.getFirstHeader("Location").getValue());
```

во-первых такого заголовка нет, а во-вторых передается предупреждение:

> бер. 07, 2016 9:13:13 PM
>   org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
>   WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: remixlang=1; expires=Fri,
>   03 Mar 2017 14:08:26 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com". Invalid 'expires'
>   attribute: Fri, 03 Mar 2017 14:08:26 GMT
>
> бер. 07, 2016 9:13:13 PM
>   org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
>   WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie:
>   remixlhk=b0535962ec9c2dcee2; expires=Thu, 16 Mar 2017 11:05:21 GMT;
>   path=/; domain=.vk.com". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Thu, 16 Mar 2017
>   11:05:21 GMT

Сервер возвращает код 200

От сервера я получаю вот такие Headers:

> Server: Apache   Date: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 21:28:09 GMT   Content-Type:
>   text/html; charset=utf-8   Connection: keep-alive   X-Powered-By:
>   PHP/3.21901   Set-Cookie: remixlang=1; expires=Sat, 04 Mar 2017
>   18:01:50 GMT; path=/;   domain=.vk.com   Set-Cookie:
>   remixlhk=0e65abac9fd62d58fc; expires=Tue, 28 Feb 2017 17:46:12 GMT; 
>   path=/; domain=.vk.com   Pragma: no-cache   Cache-control: no-store
>   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Уже опускаются руки.. Подскажите как вообще делается авторизация(вконтакте или любой другой сайт с формой)? Потому что пытаюсь на другом сайте получить заголовок "location" - его нет в ответе. Подскажите алгоритм или где и что почитать именно по практической части?

Comment: какой ответ возвращается от сервера? нужно добавить в вопрос.

Comment: сервер возвращает ОК. Или что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: полный ответ, http headers и http body, если оно есть

Comment: Почитайте в гугле, что такое 200 ОК и когда может присутствовать заголовок location

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, почитаю конечно, но проблема то не совсем в этом.. Дело в том что для авторизации этот заголовок в любом случае должен присутствовать ведь..

Comment: @MichaelEn ну да, реальная проблема не в этом, реальная проблема в том, что вы не читали документацию ВК, а там написано, что он имеет полное право прислать веб-страницу, в которой пользователь должен нажать кнопочку или даже ввести логин с паролем, и именно её он здесь, собственно, и присылает :)

Comment: я не ванга чтобы угадывать, но чувствую что ВК присылает в ответ окошко где пользователю нужно нажать на кнопку чтобы авторизовать приложение

Answer (score 3):

Лучшим выбором модуля спринга, который работает с социальными сетям (не только авторизация) является [Spring Social](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/). Он полностью интегрирован с Spring Security. В сети очень много разных примеров как подключать авторизацию через соц сети(с помощью ss), по тем же протоколам OAuth, OAuth2 или Spring Boot'ом, что еще проще. 
Кроме этого, там не только фб, твиттер и гугл. В примерах можно найти и вк и множество даже самых непопулярных сайтов.

Answer (score 0):

Если используешь spring security, то могу порекомендовать авторизацию через ulogin.ru и использование и интеграцию ulogin и spring_security: https://github.com/dmrzh/ulogin_spring_security